How can I add multiple class to revealjs slides in quarto
I can enable a scrolling in a slide by adding {.scrollable} to the slide's title and updating the YAML
---
format: 
    revealjs:
        scrollable: true
---

## Inferences from Posterior for Treatment Effect {.scrollable}

I am unclear on how to add multiple classes for scrolling and no stretch. 
The following fail:
## Inferences from Posterior for Treatment Effect {.scrollable, .nostretch}
## Inferences from Posterior for Treatment Effect {.scrollable} {.nostretch}

I am including an image of scrolling for reference


Try ## Inferences from Posterior for Treatment Effect {.scrollable .nostretch}

@Julian that is the correct solution. please supply as an answer so I can give you credit

You can add multiple classes just by simply lining them up one after the other, i.e.
## Inferences from Posterior for Treatment Effect {.scrollable .nostretch}

